# Powershell convert String to System.Net.IPAddress

Tags: powershell, ip

I'm new to powershell and I'm trying to automate creating a DHCP reservation.

So far I'm able to get the IP address like so:

```
$IP = ( GEt-VM -ComputerName $HVCOMPUTERNAME -VMName $HVNAME | Get-VMNetworkAdapter).IpAddresses[0]
```

This returns a string like:

```
192.0.2.1
```

However, the Add-DhcpServer4Resrvation cmdlet does not accept an ip address as a string. It requires the IP address be a 'System.Net.IpAddress'

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ComputerName $DHCPServer -ScopeId $DHCPScope -IPAddress $IP -Client
Id $MacAddress -Name $HVNAME

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'IPAddress'. Cannot convert value "
10.254.130.104
" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."
At line:1 char:86
+ ... ope -IPAddress $IP -ClientId $MacAddress -Name $HVNAME
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation
```

How do you convert a string to a System,.Net.IPAddress?

According [to this link](http://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2014/6/18/powershell-tip-validating-ip-address-as-a-parameter), it should be easy like

```
> [ipaddress]"192.0.2.1"
```

However that doesn't work.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $FOO = [IPAddress]$IP
Cannot convert value "
10.254.130.104
" to type "System.Net.IPAddress". Error: "An invalid IP address was specified."
At line:1 char:1
+ $FOO = [IPAddress]$IP
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocation
                   tworkAdapter) Format-List -Property *.254.13༁爼ሂÌGEt-VM -ComputerName $HVCOMPUTERNAME -VMName $HVNAME | Get-VMNetworkAdapter) | Format-List -Property *    {༁牎ᐂÊGEt-VM -ComputerName $HVCOMPUTERNAME -VMName $HVNAME | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Format-List -Property *
ఁ牘ࠂÆ$IP = ( GEt-VM -ComputerName $HVCOMPUTERNAME -VMName $HVNAME | Gt-VMNex뿰bpte
```

Related question
[Powershell, get ip4v address of VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976454/powershell-get-ip4v-address-of-vm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[IPAddress]` Wont work if there are spaces in the string

Remove them with Trim()

```
$IP = [IPAddress]$IP.Trim()
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that this is the case for all whitespace, not just spaces. If your string has leading or trailing tabs or blank lines in it those would also be removed with the `.Trim()` method, so the answer works in general, but there are things other than just spaces that are removed that way.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach for obtaining IP Address of a server is:

by passing the Workstation/Server name as a parameter to the input type System.Net.DNS cast

For example, if the FQDN name of the host is ABCTest-DEV, then the following script will reveal the IP address of ABCTest-Dev provided, the host has a DNS record already available in the domain.

```bsh
$ipaddr = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses('ABCTest-Dev')|Where AddressFamily -EQ 'InterNetwork'
Write-Host 'This IPV4 Address of the Host is: '$ipaddr
```