# How can I parse an IP address

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I have to parse to get an IP address.

```
$Currentpath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$CheminCSV = $currentpath + '\LesIP.csv'

$csv = Import-Csv $CheminCSV

$MyIPS = $csv | select IP

$MyHostnames = $csv | select HostName

Write-Host($MyIPS[1])
```

The actual results are:

```
@{IP=192.168.1.10}
```

and I expect:

```
192.168.1.10
```

Comment: [Powershell convert String to System.Net.IPAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977500/powershell-convert-string-to-system-net-ipaddress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a parsing issue. Your CSV has a header for "IP". If you import this CSV, you get an object with a property "IP", which you assign to `$MyIPS`.

You can get your expected output by `$MyIPS[1].IP`. Or you simple change your `select` (i.e. `select-object -Property`) to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IP`.